# Add message store spring integration dsl

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, cqengine

I am currently looking at the options to add real-time tracking of all the messages going over in my application.

I have enabled **messagehistory** so technically I'll get all the steps happened during the flow.

Now I want to store each message with the history in disk cache using **CQEngine** as it has great support and is very quick.

Then from the UI I'll show the message and history and display using **GraphVIZ** so the users can actually see the lifecycle of each message with diagram.

**Option # 01**

Add the call in the handle() method in each flow to add the message and history asynchrnously in the disk cache.

But this means I'll have to manually do that every time for new flow.

> Is there any option 02 I can utilize like adding interceptor etc that
>   will be called whenever a flow is completed succesfully or
>   un-sucessfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `WireTap` interceptor for channels: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/core.html#channel-interceptors.
And configure a global channel interceptor pattern for that wire-tap to specify those channels you would like to track. The same doc has info on the matter. Also see annotation configuration on the matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations

Comment: Is there any example or sample you might have I can use reference? When I use the WireTap I only see the original message recieved but not the one which I see in handle method.

Comment: Do you use wire-tap exactly on the channel before that handle? You may need specify an explicit channel in the flow though

Comment: Yes I have setup the wiretap just before handle. Is that right?

Comment: Actually it worked. It does matter the locate of wiretap in the lofw

Comment: That's correct. It really matters. See WireTap docs starting from `log()`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-log

Comment: Quick question how can I make the wireTap as ASYNC right now I see the handle method is only called after it has finished with wireTap

Comment: WireTap can be configured with a channel and no one stops you to use a QueueChannel or an ExecutorChannel. So, this way all your tapping logic is going to be asynchronous.

Comment: Any example with that ? It will help

Comment: Not sure what you expect from me because there is no more than overloaded `wireTap()` method in DSL with a channel (or its name) argument. See also WireTap pattern description in the doc I mentioned in my answer. It main point is indeed a channel to send an intercepted message.

Comment: I understand. Probably I'll have asynchronous service inside that wiretap channel flow.